# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xe9103aa560080 in tid 31072 (ReferenceQueueD), pid 31058

Tags: android, android-ndk, usb, stack-trace, fatal-error

My app is not crashing always, just after a while that i am working with it, it will crash.

i found other's solutions but they didn't help me.

**Here's my tombstone trace:**

```
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xe9103aa560080
    x0  fe0e9103aa560080  x1  0000007338cb3b74  x2  000000741bc58080  x3  0000007329716980
    x4  000000006f934234  x5  0000007397cd87d2  x6  0000007338cb37fc  x7  0000000000000000
    x8  3aa600b8aa7abcf2  x9  3aa600b8aa7abcf2  x10 0000000000430000  x11 00000073980db1dc
    x12 00000073980db224  x13 00000073980db26c  x14 00000073980db2cc  x15 0000000000000000
    x16 0000007338cb3b60  x17 0000000000000bc3  x18 0000007338516000  x19 0000007329716980
    x20 000000738fc3d9f0  x21 000000741bc58080  x22 0000000015084a50  x23 0000007329716980
    x24 0000000000000004  x25 0000007338cb5020  x26 0000007386e524b0  x27 0000000000000001
    x28 0000000000000000  x29 0000007338cb3b50
    sp  0000007338cb3b40  lr  0000000070ae4c44  pc  000000741bc5809c
```

**back stack trace :**

```
  #00 pc 000000000015409c  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (Bitmap_destruct(android::BitmapWrapper*)+28) (BuildId: 16a538ae30ac9b23d3aa61ecd2f04993)
      #01 pc 000000000004cc40  /system/framework/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (art_jni_trampoline+160) (BuildId: 1b333cb995e16deed34376285a37e8437bc6b597)
      #02 pc 00000000020b891c  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (libcore.util.NativeAllocationRegistry$CleanerThunk.run+92)
      #03 pc 00000000020dc418  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (sun.misc.Cleaner.clean+104)
      #04 pc 0000000000136334  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548) (BuildId: 93d83fbe5f93534e033d3a843284933f)
      #05 pc 0000000000145068  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+244) (BuildId: 93d83fbe5f93534e033d3a843284933f)
      #06 pc 00000000002df390  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+384) (BuildId: 93d83fbe5f93534e033d3a843284933f)
      #07 pc 00000000002da670  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+912) (BuildId: 93d83fbe5f93534e033d3a843284933f)
      #08 pc 0000000000597adc  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+648) (BuildId: 93d83fbe5f93534e033d3a843284933f)
      #09 pc 0000000000130814  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 93d83fbe5f93534e033d3a843284933f)
      #10 pc 00000000000f02fc  /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-oj.jar (java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.enqueueLocked+28)
      #11 pc 000000000059a17c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+1168) (BuildId: 93d83fbe5f93534e033d3a843284933f)
      #12 pc 0000000000130914  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_direct+20) (BuildId: 93d83fbe5f93534e033d3a843284933f)
      #13 pc 00000000000f05d2  /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-oj.jar (java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.enqueuePending+38)
      #14 pc 000000000059a988  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+1136) (BuildId: 93d83fbe5f93534e033d3a843284933f)
      #15 pc 0000000000130994  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static+20) (BuildId: 93d83fbe5f93534e033d3a843284933f)
      #16 pc 00000000001a9604  /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-libart.jar (java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.runInternal+52)
      #17 pc 0000000000597dec  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1432) (BuildId: 93d83fbe5f93534e033d3a843284933f)
      #18 pc 0000000000130814  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 93d83fbe5f93534e033d3a843284933f)
      #19 pc 00000000001a8d32  /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-libart.jar (java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run+50)
      #20 pc 00000000005995e0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface+1740) (BuildId: 93d83fbe5f93534e033d3a843284933f)
      #21 pc 0000000000130a14  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_interface+20) (BuildId: 93d83fbe5f93534e033d3a843284933f)
      #22 pc 00000000000e4a6c  /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-oj.jar (java.lang.Thread.run+8)
      #23 pc 00000000002affdc  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEbb.llvm.1271440803783865717+240) (BuildId: 93d83fbe5f93534e033d3a843284933f)
      #24 pc 0000000000589124  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1012) (BuildId: 93d83fbe5f93534e033d3a843284933f)
      #25 pc 000000000013f468  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+88) (BuildId: 93d83fbe5f93534e033d3a843284933f)
      #26 pc 0000000000136334  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548) (BuildId: 93d83fbe5f93534e033d3a843284933f)
      #27 pc 0000000000145068  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+244) (BuildId: 93d83fbe5f93534e033d3a843284933f)
      #28 pc 00000000004a93a8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+104) (BuildId: 93d83fbe5f93534e033d3a843284933f)
      #29 pc 00000000004aa43c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValues(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, jvalue const*)+416) (BuildId: 93d83fbe5f93534e033d3a843284933f)
      #30 pc 00000000004ea1d4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*)+1176) (BuildId: 93d83fbe5f93534e033d3a843284933f)
      #31 pc 00000000000e2390  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36) (BuildId: 1ff700b4bab84f60b75913d4e6d82960)
      #32 pc 0000000000083ab0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64) (BuildId: 1ff700b4bab84f60b75913d4e6d82960)
```

How should i solve this issue?

Comment: What did the app try to do when this happened? What verion of Android? What device?

Comment: the app is working with usb device, Android 10 LineageOS , Odroid N2.

Comment: So a custom ROM. This could be an error in the ROM. You could eliminate that by getting a USB OTG adapter and running the app on an Android phone with original ROM.

Comment: i must install my app in odroid n2. odroid's OS is LineageOS. what else i could install?

Comment: You should figure out on which line of your code it's crashing, otherwise no clues what may cause the crash. And post some of your related code to understand what may be the cause.

Comment: @Hack06 the problem is that i cant figure it out wher the crash line code is.

Comment: @HoseinHaqiqian then at least post some code for people to take a look at, if you want to get help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was because of a library which is image processor.
i removed the library and re-implemented feature myself ,then problem solved.

Comment: Hi, which library caused the problem? Thanks